# Generate a jar executable file using maven from a proactive client with an infinite loop

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, jar, client

We are basically writing a client in spring boot that acts proactively connecting to a server and gets some data change and then process the data and send it to repository. My question is as follows:

While running the maven install the whole spring boot app starts running, but the client stays connected to the server forever. Hence can't terminate the run and generate the jar file.

Any suggestions fellows?

Comment: Your problem is with infinite loop. Put some logic and break it while you client application has problem.

Comment: Post your maven config and how you start your maven task at least